# How to validate the mandatory question in VF page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, validation, rerender

I have a requirement to display the set of questions in VF Page. The set of questions will be available in Custom object. I need to display the question field and answer field for the user to answer. I have a Is_Mandatory check box in custom object where user can set the questions as mandatory. What I need to do is I have to populate the mandatory questions with (*) symbol. And I have to do a validation check when the user click the submit button whether all the mandatory question are filled or not. Can anyone please guide me on this?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming your object structure is:

```
Your Object
    Is_Mandatory__c
    Question_1__c, Answer_1__c
    Question_2__c, Answer_2__c
    Question_3__c, Answer_3__c
    ...
    Question_N__c, Answer_N__c
```

You should include the [`<apex:pageMessages/>`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_pageMessages.htm) in your Visualforce page to display the error message(s).

You can use conditional output to render the asterisk (*).  You might have to play with the formatting a bit for your specific Visualforce layout.

```
<apex:outputText value="*" rendered="{!yourRecord.Is_Mandatory__c}"/> <apex:inputField value="{!yourRecord.Question_1__c}"/> 
<apex:outputText value="*" rendered="{!yourRecord.Is_Mandatory__c}"/> <apex:inputField value="{!yourRecord.Question_2__c}"/> 
<apex:outputText value="*" rendered="{!yourRecord.Is_Mandatory__c}"/> <apex:inputField value="{!yourRecord.Question_3__c}"/>
<apex:outputText value="*" rendered="{!yourRecord.Is_Mandatory__c}"/> <apex:inputField value="{!yourRecord.Question_N__c}"/>
```

For the validation, you could create a [Validation Rule](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_defining_field_validation_rules.htm&language=en_US) that doesn't allow the record to be saved if Is_Mandatory__c = true and any of the Answer__c fields are blank.  Then in your controller you will have to catch the DMLException and disply the error message.

```
public PageReference submit() {
    try {
        //insert/update/upsert your record
        upsert yourRecord;
     } catch(DmlException ex){
         ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
     }
}
```

Alternatively, you could validate in your Controller:

```
public PageReference submit() {
    if (yourRecord.Is_Mandatory__c) {
        if (hasBlankAnswer()) {
            ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'All answers are required');
            ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
            return null;
        }
    }
}

private Boolean hasBlankAnswer() {
    // check for blank answers...
    // return true if there are any, false otherwise.
}
```